# python dictmixin object with property decorator

Tags: python, properties, dictmixin

I was instructed to use more pythonish way of setter and getters @property. So we have something like this:

```
from UserDict import DictMixin

class A(dict):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._a

    @a.setter
    def a(self, value):
        self._a = value

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return getattr(self, key)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        setattr(self, key, value)

    def keys(self):
        return [k for k in self.__dict__.keys() if not k.startswith('_')]

    def do_whatever(self):
        pass


a = A(1,2)
print a.keys()
```

output is ['b'] and at first I wasn't expecting that, but it actually makes sense.

Question is how to get all properties names but not names of methods. Any ideas?

Comment: I could make method keys() return hardcoded list of properties' names, but that seems to be sooo not cool.

Comment: Any reason you're using `DictMixin` - that's a bit old now - what are you trying to do? (Create a `dict` that also supports attribute access for instance)?

Comment: I want a object with methods that I could use like a dict. Accessing a['a']

Comment: Unless you're using an old version of Python, just use `class mydict(dict)` for instance

Comment: I did that and still self.__dict__ doesn't contain attribute a.

Answer (score 0):

Properties are implemented as [descriptors](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#descriptors), and so belong to the *class*, not the *instance*:

```
>>> class Question(object):
...     @property
...     def answer(self):
...         return 7 * 6
... 
>>> q = Question()
>>> q.answer
42
>>> q.__dict__
{}
>>> for key, value in Question.__dict__.iteritems():
...     if isinstance(value, property):
...         print key
...
answer
```